# Uploading text file to mySql in apache server

Tags: mysql, apache

In my project, RFId tags are read by the reader and the info is stored in a text file. I want this text file to be uploaded ( or somehow copied) to the phpmyadmin in apache server so that i may do further processing and display result on a website. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Read the text file and make and array, which you import in the phpmyadmin using a loop.

```
<?php
$file_name = "filename.txt";
$lines = file($file_name);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
$sql_query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name(column1) VALUES ('$line')");
}
?>
```